# JQL - Each time I use parent != "CT-123" the filter hides something that is not in that EPIC

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to setup a filter in JQL, everything works fine but as soon as I add (even if I that is the only thing I add) parent != CT-123, the filter hides another task that is not inside the epic CT-123 and is actually on a different project than the one where CT-123 is.
What can it be?
[image: Current path]

[image: Task that gets hidden when it shouldn't]

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with the following:

```
(parent IS EMPTY OR parent IS NOT EMPTY AND parent != CT-123)
```

Comment: You don't need to set `parent IS NOT EMPTY`.

You can only set : `(parent IS EMPTY OR parent != CT-123)`